# Pandas replace random cells with index values as string

Tags: pandas, numpy

I have a relatively large dataframe. For ten percent of rows (selected at random) I would like to replace one cell (selected at random for each row) with a string that contains the row and column index of the cell. I would also like to append the value that is replaced to a list.

So ten percent of rows will end up with some column that looks like *STR_200305_10* or something along those lines.

I've found replacing random values to be pretty easy, but replacing them with a unique string has proven much more difficult. Any ideas about how to do this in an efficient manner?

Comment: Two options come to mind, you could just keep a counter and append that to the string as you go through. Or you could just use the uuid python module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Randomly select rows, then randomly select columns. Create the list of strings you need to replace, then drop down to `numpy` to re-create the DataFrame.

#### Sample Data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(0, 1, (10, 5)), 
                  columns=range(10,15), index=range(100,110))
```

---

```
frac = 0.4
idx = np.random.choice(range(df.shape[0]), int(df.shape[0]*frac), replace=True)
cols = np.random.choice(range(df.shape[1]), size=len(idx), replace=True)
to_repl = [f'STR_{df.index[i]}_{df.columns[col]}' for i,col in zip(idx, cols)]
#['STR_108_10', 'STR_100_10', 'STR_108_13', 'STR_106_12']

x = df.astype(object).to_numpy()
x[idx, cols] = to_repl
pd.DataFrame(x, index=df.index, columns=df.columns)
```

---

```
             10        11          12          13        14
100  STR_100_10 -0.138264    0.647689     1.52303 -0.234153
101   -0.234137   1.57921    0.767435   -0.469474   0.54256
102   -0.463418  -0.46573    0.241962    -1.91328  -1.72492
103   -0.562288  -1.01283    0.314247   -0.908024   -1.4123
104     1.46565 -0.225776   0.0675282    -1.42475 -0.544383
105    0.110923  -1.15099    0.375698   -0.600639 -0.291694
106   -0.601707   1.85228  STR_106_12    -1.05771  0.822545
107    -1.22084  0.208864    -1.95967    -1.32819  0.196861
108  STR_108_10  0.171368   -0.115648  STR_108_13  -1.47852
109   -0.719844 -0.460639     1.05712    0.343618  -1.76304
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. One detail is that I will change the replace flag for the idx to False. I don't want to make multiple replacements in the same row.